# publish asp.net with MS Access database

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, publishing

i created contact tracing web app  and how do i deploy my asp.net web app with ms access database will i get error because of the database path directory in my code? like the "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Windows 10\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ContactMvc\Weblogin.mdb"

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you need first to ensure that the web site has support for the Access data engine. I mean, if you build a asp.net web site with Oracle, or say MySQL database, then that web site has to have the MySQL database system, or the oracle database system, or maybe your using SQL server.

Next up:
The path name to the folder on the web site is going to change. We assume that the accDB database file is in some folder.

You web site say might be like this:

So in above, your folder with the database will be in app_data for example.

When you publish to the web server, that folder could be placed who knows where! - but it WILL BE just a standard windows folder.

What this suggests then is you need to convert that folder path above into a valid plane jane windows file path.

So, in above, the folder path might resolve to:

c:\webpub\wwworoot\app_data\MyData.accDB

So, you need to do this:

```
strDataBasePath = Server.MapPath("~/app_data/Weblogin.mdb")
```

You could also edit the connection string in web config before you publish. So the new location will change for the publish. It not clear if this is a web hosted server or a local server on your network. But, you have to look at the final published location, and hard code (edit) the connection string you have in web config, or create a public application wide routine that uses Server.MapPath to convert the web folder path name into a valid plane jane windows file path name.

This thus suggests that the Weblogin.mdb file has to be in the folder hierarchy of the folders used in the web site (and can't be outside of the wwwroot folder systems for the the path name.

Given that you are ONLY able to use tables from that access database, and not other access features, then often it preferable to use a database server system like SQl server etc., since in that case you don't connect using a valid path name to a file, but in fact can use a connection string, and this is often less hassle or efforts on your part.

So for a test web site, or very light workloads, you can use an access database, but it not really recommended to do this. (access is file based, and not really good at say handling multiple requests and what we call threaded code). So for learning, or testing, then fine. And for a very light user load, then again access can be used. But the only real benefits is you perhaps save the time and learning of having to setup and use a real database server, of which web sites work much better with then say access ones.